# How to pass client id and secret in laravel http request with grant type?

Tags: laravel-7

I'm trying to get token from endpoint which requires client ID and client secret for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

$response = Http::withBasicAuth(CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_SECRET)
                ->post(TOKEN_URL . '?grant_type=client_credentials')

return $response->json(); 
// response contains following array

array:4 [▼
  "access_token" => "YOUR_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN"
  "token_type" => "bearer"
  "expires_in" => 42678
  "scope" => "read:* update:*"
] 

***Note:*** I used this for getting chatkitty token
```